# Zipping zippers in Anti-XML

Tags: xml, scala, zipper, anti-xml

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130684/334519), the asker wants to transform documents like this:

```
<text>
  The capitals of Bolivia are <blank/> and <blank/>.
</text>
```

Into this:

```
<text>
  The capitals of Bolivia are <input name="blank.1"> and <input name="blank.2">.
</text>
```

As I noted in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143012/334519), [Anti-XML](http://anti-xml.org/)'s [zippers](http://anti-xml.org/zippers.html) provide a clean solution to this problem. The following, for example, would work for renaming the blank elements:

```
import com.codecommit.antixml._

val q = <text>The capitals of Bolivia are <blank/> and <blank/>.</text>.convert

(q \\ "blank").map(_.copy(name = "input")).unselect
```

Unfortunately the following doesn't work:

```
(q \\ "blank").zipWithIndex.map { case (el, i) => el.copy(
  name = "input",
  attrs = Attributes("name" -> "blank.%d".format(i + 1))
)}.unselect
```

Because of course once we've `zipWithIndex`-ed the zipper we no longer have a zipper, just an `IndexedSeq`—we can't have a `Zipper[(Node, Int)]` because the definition is `trait Zipper[+A <: Node] ...`.

Is there a clean way to use `zip` or `zipWithIndex` on an Anti-XML zipper, do some other operations with `map`, etc., and end up with something that's still a zipper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a direct way to achieve what you need, but if you're willing to go for a lower level function, you can use a `fold`, e.g.:

```
val blanks = q \\ "blank"

(0 until blanks.size).foldLeft(blanks) {case (z, i) => z.updated(i, z(i).copy(
  name = "input",
  attrs = Attributes("name" -> "blank.%d".format(i + 1)))
)}.unselect
```

Note that the zipper is a random access container, so efficiency shouldn't be an issue in this case.